# Ajax получить данные от сервера

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Как получить данные, полученные от сервера, в php массив?

Делаю поиск. Посылаю данные на сервер из файла `index.php`:

```
$(function() {
    $(".mys").keyup(function() {
        var search_1 = $("#search_1").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: {
                "search1": search_1
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                //$("#tbl").hide();
                $("#result").html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Там я уже делаю запрос в БД и вывожу данные с помощью `echo`. Ну и потом вывожу полученные данные:

```
$("#result").html(response)
```

Это всё через jQuery выводится, а я хочу ещё в php коде их обработать и вывести.

Comment: Уточните, что именно вы хотите получить и в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: Я хочу получить данные из страници search.php на страницу index.php.
Только не в  JS, а PHP.

Comment: Так допишите обработчик в конце `search.php`..